# Marmalade Flurry

Tags: flurry, marmalade

Wrote simple code using Marmalade with EDK Flurry.

app only start's session, send one log event and stops.

On Motorola Flipout this app work fine witout crash.

But on Samsung Galaxy Tab its crashing.
It's log from logcat:

> 11-21 15:00:31.608: W/dalvikvm(13139): JNI WARNING: 0x485c7c40 is not a valid JNI reference
> 11-21 15:00:31.608: W/dalvikvm(13139):              in Lcom/ideaworks3d/marmalade/LoaderThread;.runNative (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V (GetMethodID)
>
> 11-21 15:00:31.608: I/dalvikvm(13139): "Thread-9" prio=5 tid=8 RUNNABLE
> 11-21 15:00:31.612: I/dalvikvm(13139):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x485d9a20 self=0x249730
>
> 11-21 15:00:31.616: I/dalvikvm(13139):   | sysTid=13146 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=2397632
>
> 11-21 15:00:31.619: I/dalvikvm(13139):   at com.ideaworks3d.marmalade.LoaderThread.runNative(Native Method)
>
> 11-21 15:00:31.619: I/dalvikvm(13139):   at com.ideaworks3d.marmalade.LoaderThread.run(LoaderThread.java:712)
>
> 11-21 15:00:31.627: E/dalvikvm(13139): VM aborting

**Update:**  Code:-

```
#include "flurry.h"
#include "IwGx.h"

int main()
{
       
        IwGxInit();
        IwGxSetColClear(0,0,0xff,0xff);
 
 
        char* i = new char[2];
        i[0] = 9 + 48;
        i[0] = Flurry::InitFlurry() + 48;
        i[1] = '\0';
            //Flurry::SetUniqueUserID();
 
 
        while(!s3eDeviceCheckPauseRequest())
        {
                IwGxClear();
             
                IwGxPrintString(30, 100, "Flurry D");
                IwGxPrintString(30, 110, "Init code");
                IwGxPrintString(30, 120 , i);
                IwGxFlush();
                IwGxSwapBuffers();
 
                s3eDeviceYield(0);
        }
 
        Flurry::ExitFlurry();
        IwGxTerminate();
        return 0;
}


#include "flurry.h"
 
#ifdef FLURRY
char* Flurry:: FLURRY_ID_ANDROID;
char* Flurry:: FLURRY_ID_IPHONE;
char Flurry:: log_error = 9;

void Flurry :: InitIDsForPlatforms()
{
        FLURRY_ID_ANDROID = new char[20];
        FLURRY_ID_IPHONE = new char[20];
        strcpy(FLURRY_ID_ANDROID, "some number");
        strcpy(FLURRY_ID_IPHONE, "some number");
};

int Flurry :: InitFlurry()
{
        //if(log_error != 9)
                //return log_error;
        //Check if Flurry is available
        if (!s3eFlurryAvailable())
        {
                Flurry::log_error = 1;
        return 1;
        }
 
        Flurry::InitIDsForPlatforms();
 
        //Enable AppCircle
        //s3eFlurryAppCircleEnable();
        return Flurry::log_error;
        //Check the OS is runing on device
        switch(s3eDeviceGetInt(S3E_DEVICE_OS))
        {
                case S3E_OS_ID_ANDROID :
                        s3eFlurryStart(Flurry::FLURRY_ID_ANDROID);
                        break;
 
                case S3E_OS_ID_IPHONE :
                        s3eFlurryStart(Flurry::FLURRY_ID_IPHONE);
                        break;
 
                default :
                        Flurry::log_error = 2;
                        return 2;
        }

    /*
            something more write?
    */
        Flurry::log_error = 0;
        return 0;
};


void Flurry :: SetUserID(const char* ID)
{
        if(!Flurry::log_error)
                s3eFlurrySetUserID(ID);
}

void Flurry :: ExitFlurry()
{
        if(!Flurry::log_error)
                s3eFlurrySetSessionReportOnClose(true);
}

void Flurry :: LogEvent(const char* data)
{
        if(!Flurry::log_error)
                s3eFlurryLogEvent(data, false);
}


void Flurry :: addParamterToLogEvent(const char* name, const char* data)
{
        if(!Flurry::log_error)
                addToHashMap(name, data);
}

void Flurry :: addParamterToLogEvent(const char* name, int data)
{
        if(Flurry::log_error)
                return;
        std::stringstream str;
        str << data;
        addToHashMap(name, str.str().c_str());
}

void Flurry :: LogEventWithParameters(const char* name)
{
        if(!Flurry::log_error)
                s3eFlurryLogEventMap(name);
}

void Flurry :: SetUniqueUserID()
{
        if(!Flurry::log_error)
                Flurry :: SetUserID(s3eDeviceGetString(S3E_DEVICE_UNIQUE_ID));
}
#endif
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/SPAyHDwG
there is code from two files